# Trying to create a Login page where it also shows that "Only password is wrong" if username is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, webforms

***ONLY FOR LEARNING PURPOSE:*** **Help me to correct the code, I'm trying to get error msg that also shows "Only the password is wrong." It always skips the bolded part of the code.**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtusername.Text != null && txtpassword.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        sql = string.Format(@" select * from idpass where username ='{0}' and password = '{1}'", txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
        DataTable dtForNameAndRole = LoadDataByQuery(sql);
        try
        {
            if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["username"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Session["password"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["password"].ToString();


                txtpassword.Text = string.Empty;
                txtusername.Text = string.Empty;
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
            }
            else if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtusername.Text = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();

                lblMessage.Text = "Wrong Password!";
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        msgtr.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Text = "Sorry! Invalid user name or password.";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Security hazard!** This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
Also, **This is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it**.  The reason is that it gives information to a potential hacker that they didn't have before. Once they know the username is valid, all they have to figure out is the password, and that makes their job much, much easier.

Comment: Thanks but It's for learning purpose. As you've guessed I'm new to asp and sql server. I want to know why can't I execute that block of the code.

Comment: You have the same check twice: `if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)`

In the bold part, either change it to **if** instead of **else if** (so that it is not skipped), or make sure that the if-check is valid/not duplicate.

Comment: @Zohar but then the number of those sites that have a forgot password page that says "we don't have a user by that name"..

Comment: when you used `if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)`  , When the first if is fell, the other sections are no longer running. You must pass the else if `(dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)` content code to the first if or write a separate by the way you used `Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");` in the first if. when first if happened then you will be taken to another page.

Comment: @Zohar and also.. meh, the security risk that introduces is a drop in the ocean compared to the massive sql injection risk this code has

Comment: @CaiusJard that's true, but the don't do it from the login page. Also note that they usually use a captcha in this page to prevent robots from scanning multiple user names atomatically.

Comment: @CaiusJard that's why I've started with sql injection....

Comment: @Mir have you considered making logon someone else's problem (auth0 for example). - at the very least, read http://Bobby-tables.com and also Google for "vtech hack" to get a sense of the size of the security hole your login form opens up. This code, as is, should never be put into production

Comment: @zohar yeah but leading with a couple of words on SQLinj then going into detail on "it's a bad idea to be explicit about whether un or pw is wrong" might lead someone to assume the wrong priorities..

Comment: *It's for learning purpose* - that's a great reason why you should learn and practice getting it right.. never write off security to "blah, it's just some internal only app that will never be put on the internet". You're also storing passwords in plain text.. should nominate his code for an award as to how many security no-no's one bit of code can have

Comment: If you do want to persist with a route of "only password is wrong" then you cannot do a sql of "username = @u and password =@p" because you never know why it found no records. You do a "user = @u" only and if it finds no record hen username is wrong, if it finds but the salted hashed password bytes of the input do not match the salted hashed pw bytes retrieved from the db hen the pw is wrong

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually, I've started my comment before reading the code. I've edited in the SQL injection part only after I've published my comment, that's why it was elaborated on the other issue. You do have a point there, though. Also there's the part of storing plain-text passwords in the database that I didn't mention... All in all, I think it's a bit too wide for a simple SO comment.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Zohar Peled Stated this aproach is against all security conventions, don't do it in production.

But if you want to do it, you must check first the user and then the password (that normally would be hashed so you'll need some additional work if thats the case.

ALSO you need to parametrice your query so the LoadDataByQuery function MUST be reworked

All this said let's do this completly UNSECURE login work as you want:

```
        string sql = string.Format(@" select * from idpass where username = @userName");
        SqlParameterCollection parameters =  new SqlParameterCollection();
        var parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "userName";
        parameter.Value =  txtusername.Text;
        parameters.Add(parameter);
        DataTable dtForNameAndRole = LoadDataByQueryAndParameters(sql, parameters);
        try
        {

            if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["password"].ToString() == txtpassword.Text)
                {
                    Session["username"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                    Session["password"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["password"].ToString();


                    txtpassword.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtusername.Text = string.Empty;
                    Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                }
                else 
                {
                    txtusername.Text = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();

                    lblMessage.Text = "Wrong Password!";
                }
                
            }
[continue your code after the ** // **]
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do, will suppose the LoadDataByQuery  is done correctly then.

Comment: @CaiusJard I get your point, thanks but I've just started to learn ASP and SQL servers on my own, after learning the basics I'll do some premium course. So my friend who is helping me for the basics has given me some tasks which I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Caius is right, StackOverflow is a place where lot of peope come and just copy & paste, so I rewrote my answer to parametrize your query SQL Injection is no joke, and if you're learning, better a really basic concept like this be clear from start

Comment: Now all the code needs is a helper `private static string GetHash(string text) => Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));` and replace the password compare `== txtpassword.Text` with `== GetHash("saltee123"+txtpassword.Text)` with a footnote to pick another salt and do the same on the saving routine.. 

Comment: @CaiusJard. Perhaps Rfc2898DeriveBytes would be better?

Comment: Sure, drop a recommendation in